# C# Newtonsof duplicado

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

actualmente estoy dersrrollando una aplicacion que requiere el uso de newtonsoft para convertir objetos a json, pero al intentar convertirlos me marca error ya que al parecer encuentra dos verciones de newtonsoft (6 y 12), al revisar las referencias solo aparece la 12, incluso en el explorador de paquetes Nuget, pero me enconter con esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si hay dos versiones en el proyecto, mi pregunta es como puedo eliminar la version 6 ya que solo aparece en el examinador de objetos y desde ahi no puedo eliminarlo.

NOTA: ya elimine la carpeta del disco, limpie solucion, etc. y sigue apareciendo

Answer (score 0):

Consolida las versiones:
`Herramientas > Administrador de Paquetes Nuget > Administrar paquetes nuget para la solución...`

Ahí existe una pestaña llamada "`Consolidar`" donde podrás ver las versiones utilizadas de cada paquete en cada proyecto y seleccionar con cuál de todas te quedarás

Comment: No me aparece ningún paquete en esa pestaña, ya le di en todo a "Origen del paquete"

Comment: Al parecer la version 6 la esta obteniendo desde esta ruta (aun cuanfdo no esta importada):
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\plugins\Diagnostics\Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Comment: En la pestaña "instalado" sí aparece algo?

Comment: Si, la versión 12 de newtonsoft y todos los paquetes que tengo instalados

Comment: Listo, lo resolvi eliminando newtonsoft.json.dll de la version 6 en los lugares del disco que aparece, no se a que se deba que tome en automatico referencias de lugares externos al proyecto pero este fue el problema.

C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\